# Firebase StorageReference.listAll() completion handler unexpectedly fires twice in error case

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, error-handling, firebase-storage

I'm writing an iOS app and I want to list all the files in a Firebase Storage folder. If I understand correctly, the way to do this is to use the StorageReference.listAll() function, which takes a completion handler as its parameter. The problem is that in an error case - for example if the user is offline - this handler fires twice: the first time with an error, the second time without. Here's my code, simplified for the purposes of this question:

```
let storageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child(userID)
storageReference.listAll { (result, error) in

  print("handler fires")

  if let error = error {
    print("error")
  } else {
    print("no error")
  }
}
```

In the regular case, this outputs "handler fires", "no error" which is what one would expect. If the user is offline, however, it outputs "handler fires", "error", "handler fires", "no error", which seems strange. Does anyone know why the handler is firing twice in the error case, and why the second of these firings reports no error?

Here is the full error log:

> handler fires

> Error description: Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx.appspot.com/o?prefix=xxx/&delimiter=/, NSUnderlyingError=0x282dcdc80 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxx.appspot.com/o?prefix=xxx/&delimiter=/,_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=("LocalDataTask <1487E789-1446-42FF-9F5F-EEF8AD4370E1>.<4>"), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <1487E789-1446-42FF-9F5F-EEF8AD4370E1>.<4>, kGTMSessionFetcherElapsedIntervalWithRetriesKey=14.007386088371277, kGTMSessionFetcherNumberOfRetriesDoneKey=3, ResponseErrorDomain=NSURLErrorDomain, bucket=xxx.appspot.com, object=xxx, ResponseErrorCode=-1009, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.}

> handler fires

> No error

Comment: *firebaser here* I checked with our SDK team, and a call to `listAll()` should only trigger the callback once. There's nothing like a reconnect listener in the SDK to recheck any previous `listAll()` calls on reconnect, so I don't see how it could even fire multiple times. Are you sure you're not calling `listAll` multiple times?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen. Thanks for looking into this. I've checked and my code definitely does not call listAll() twice. In the success case, the handler only fires once and there's nothing in the `if let error = error {}` segment which could trigger a second call: it only contains `print ("error")`. I'm using Firebase Storage version 6.27.1

Comment: What is the `error` you get when offline?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If I have `if let error = error {print("Error description: \(error.debugDescription)") }`, I get output which begins: "Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response."" The full error log is too long for a comment here, but let me know if you'd like me to message it to you. There's nothing in there that looks surprising to my eye.

Comment: Please include the error message in your question. There's an `edit` link right under your question for adding such information.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Edited to include full error log.